# LeetCode: Unique Binary Search Trees Calculation

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, catalan

Given n, how many structurally unique BST's (binary search trees) that store values 1...n?

For example,
Given n = 3, there are a total of 5 unique BST's.

```
   1         3     3      2      1
    \       /     /      / \      \
     3     2     1      1   3      2
    /     /       \                 \
   2     1         2                 3
```

I've got this solution:

```
/**
 * Solution:
 * DP
 * a BST can be destruct to root, left subtree and right subtree.
 * if the root is fixed, every combination of unique left/right subtrees forms
 * a unique BST.
 * Let a[n] = number of unique BST's given values 1..n, then
 * a[n] = a[0] * a[n-1]     // put 1 at root, 2...n right
 *      + a[1] * a[n-2]     // put 2 at root, 1 left, 3...n right
 *      + ...
 *      + a[n-1] * a[0]     // put n at root, 1...n-1 left
 */
int numTrees(int n) {
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    vector<int> trees(n+1, 0);
    trees[0] = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
            trees[i] += trees[j] * trees[i-j-1];

    return trees[n];
}
```

Because this answer was given out too long ago to touch this *'dragonmigo'* guy.
This solution is accepted and my problem is:

In the comment, trees[0] refers to case *1*. (0+1 = 1)

If so, trees[n-1] should refer to case *1...n* rather than the case *2...n*. (n-1+1=n)

Is my thinking wrong?

p.s. I know this is actually a Catalan number and I know the algorithm using the deduction formula to solve it.

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you want to ask? It is Catalan Number. Do you want it's proof or anything else?

Comment: That's not my point. My point is the definition of trees[n] in comment conflicts with the actual meaning of trees[n] in code.

Comment: Just like this *Let a[n] = number of unique BST's given values 1..n* then what should a[0] represent for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`trees[n]` is the number of trees with exactly `n` nodes. There is 1 trees with 0 nodes, hence  `trees[0] == 1`. For a given `n > 0` there is a root node and two children trees whose total size is: `n-1`

- `trees[n-1]` possible trees on the left and `trees[0]` on the right
- `trees[n-2]` possible trees on the left and `trees[1]` on the right
- ...
- `trees[1]` possible trees on the left and `trees[n-1-1]` on the right
- `trees[0]` possible trees on the left and `trees[n-1]` on the right

When you have `trees[k]` possible trees on the left, and `trees[l]` on the right, it makes `trees[k]*trees[l]` possible combinations. This means:

```
trees[n] = trees[n-1]*trees[0]
         + trees[n-2]*trees[1]
         + ...
         + trees[1]*trees[n-2]
         + trees[0]*trees[n-1]
```

The outer loop compute all `trees[n]`. The inner loop compute each of these using the decomposition I shown above (and the computations of all the values before `n`).

Comment: It seems that *trees[n-1] possible trees on the left and trees[0] on the right* will lead to a result of *n-1 + 0 = n-1* nodes and so will the other parts. This alg considers of n possible conditions like: (1 node, n-1 nodes), (2 nodes, n-2 nodes), ..., (n-1 nodes, 1 nodes), doesn't it?

Comment: @Lancelod, No because: `trees[0]` is 1 not 0 and because `k` possible trees on left and `l` possible trees on the right result in `k*l` trees instead of `k+l`. The reason is for every single left tree, out of the `k` possible trees, you have `l` possible trees on the right.

Comment: I've got your point of *k x l*. It's my bad not explaining what confuses me is that in the comment, code's author wrote *"Let a[n] = number of unique BST's given values 1..n"*, and this makes the meaning of a[0] unclear(**1..0?**). Yes, my focus is how to describe what a[0] means? You say it means *1 possible trees* and as you know case *0 node* leads to *1 possible trees* and case *1 node* leads to *1 possible trees* too. What actually does this *1 possible trees* comes from? Thanks!

Comment: @Lancelod I think it's clear there is only 1 tree made of 1 node. The tricky case is understanding why there is 1 tree made of 0 node. I don't have a good philosophical reason for that. It's just convenient to use this value because it makes the other computations correct and possible, the same way we define `0! = 1` and `x^0 = 1`.  If you think about it, why does the product of 0 factors equals 1 ? The only reason is that it makes the other computations correct using a unique rule.

Comment: thanks for the patient explanation of 0. :), yet I understand why 0 node could be 1 case. It seems that only when we define a[0] as the case number of '0 node' and a[n-1] as the case number of 'n-1 nodes', this definition would have no conflicts with itself. Well, if that so, **how could combination of case '0 node' and case 'n-1 nodes' be a part of all cases of 'n nodes'?** As you can see, the node number is not *compatible*.

Comment: @Lancelod For a tree with `n` nodes, you have `1` root node and `n-1` chidlre nodes. The `n-1` children nodes are split into one left sub tree and one right sub tree. Take your 2nd example: `n = 3`, you have `1` root node, a left sub tree with `n-1 = 2` nodes and a right sub tree with `0` nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't figured it out until yesterday. Your comment is really helpful! :-)