# Finding number of Unique Binary Search Trees given `n`

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am solving an [algorithm problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-binary-search-trees/):

> Given an integer `n`, return the number of structurally unique BSTs (binary search trees) which has exactly `n` nodes of unique values from `1` to `n`.  So, for `n=3`, the output is: `5`.

This problem can be solved, as given in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755059/leetcode-unique-binary-search-trees-calculation).

***My* high level idea:**
When I first looked at the problem, I thought of simulation (using recursion and then memoizing the results): for a root `k` (1<=k<=n), calculate its prospective `left` and `right` children and check if they form a valid BST.  If yes, then increment the counter for the current root and return the counter in the end:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    unordered_set<int> visited;
    int helper(int root, int n, int l, int r, int sz) {
        if(root<=0 || root>n) return 0;
        visited.insert(root);
        if(visited.size()==n) return 1;  //visited contains all `n` nodes, so a valid BST is formed if we are here.
        
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            int left=root-i, right=root+i;
            if(left>l && left<r) {
                counter+=helper(left,n,l,root,sz+1);
            }
            if(right>l && right<r) {
                counter+=helper(right,n,root,r,sz+1);
            }
            // cout<<"-----> "<<i<<" "<<left<<" "<<right<<" "<<counter<<"\n";
        }
        return counter;
    }
    
    int numTrees(int n) {
        int counter=0, l=INT_MIN, r=INT_MAX;
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            visited.clear();
            int val=helper(i,n,l,r,1);
            // cout<<"i: "<<i<<" val: "<<val<<"\n";
            counter+=val;
        }
        return counter;
    }
};
```

This returns correct answers upto `3`, but then onwards returns wrong answers.  I am about to draw the recursion tree and dive deep, but wanted to see if my high level idea is even promising or if I am down to a wrong start.

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than check whether sub-trees are valid, I'd just assure that I only generated valid trees to start with.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, how to ensure that?

Comment: @ganpat: the key here is that the shape of the tree uniquely determines the node labels.  (All the nodes in the left subtree of the root have smaller labels and all the nodes in the right subtree have larger labels. The labels are distinct, so the root's label is one more than the number of nodes in the left subtree. Proceed by induction.) Thus, it's only necessary to enumerate binary tree shapes, which is what the linked answer does.

Comment: @rici, yes, I get that.  I also get the solution in the linked post.  But I am trying to understand where my approach of generating all the BSTs goes wrong: if I am not missing something, my approach should give correct answers, too, IMHO.

Comment: @ganpat: i don't know if I'm reading your code correctly, but it is not the case that every insertion order produces a different BST.

Comment: @rici, yes, that's a good point.  There's no way to guarantee that they are unique.